# How to import === in scalaz

Tags: scalaz

I need to use the EqualsOps (===) from scalaz, but importing scalaz.Scalaz._ gives me a naming conflict with anorm's get method.

Here is the compilation error:

```
reference to get is ambiguous;
[error] it is imported twice in the same scope by
[error] import scalaz.Scalaz._
[error] and import anorm.SqlParser._
```

How can I bring === into scope without causing the conflict with anorm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `import scalaz.Scalaz._`

Assuming you are comparing primitives,

```
import scalaz._
import std.anyVal._
import syntax.equal._
```

If it is something else, say strings, replace `std.anyVal._`, with `std.string._`.

Essentially, the first line gives you the various scalaz types (if you don't want this, replace `std` with `scalaz.std`, and syntax with `scalaz.syntax`).

Line 2 gives you the implicit conversions for the primitives. That lets you treat primitives as `Equal`, or actually as any of the other scalaz typeclasses, (`Monoid`, etc.)
Line 3 gives you `EqualOps`, which enables you to use the `===` syntax with things that can be `Equal`.

Hope that helps